# ATSC OTA tuner wanted

Tags: linux, video, television, hdtv

Looking for an ATSC (i.e., American) OTA (over the air) HDTV television tuner. PCI bus, PCIe bus, USB 2, or USB 3 all OK to use.

Must support a **Debian**/**Devuan** distro Linux media center / Personal Video Recorder app, e.g., one or more of these:

- [Emby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emby)
- [Jellyfin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jellyfin)
- [JRiver Media Center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JRiver_Media_Center)
- [Kodi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kodi_(software))
- [MythTV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MythTV)
- [NextPVR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NextPVR)
- [SageTV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SageTV)
- [Video Disk Recorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_Disk_Recorder), or
- [V@Home](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VBox_Home_TV_Gateway)

Answer (score 0):

How about network based?

https://www.silicondust.com/product/hdhomerun-duo/

HDHomeRun by silcondust

I am one right now with MythTv.

They also make "SiliconDust HDHomeRun Connect"